# PyQT Use Button Widget to Modify Other Widget in Grid

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm new to PyQT and am trying to get a firmer grasp on how signals and slots work.

I understand that I can do something like this (assuming other boilerplate is present)

```
def initUI(self):
    okButton = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
    okButton.clicked.connect(self.okClicked)

    cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")

    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    grid.addWidget(okButton, 1, 0)
    grid.addWidget(cancelButton, 2, 0)

    self.setLayout(grid)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
    self.setWindowTitle('Testing')
    self.show()

def okClicked(self):
    #How can I modify the 'cancel' button here?
```

But I can't seem to figure out how I could modify, for example, another button (or more practically a list) when okClicked is called from pushing the "OK" button. I have very little experience with GUI's in general, so if this is a silly way to go about accomplishing this task, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save a reference to whatever widgets you are interested in:

```
def initUI(self):
    self.okButton = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
    self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.okClicked)
    self.cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
    ...

def okClicked(self):
    print(self.cancelButton.text())
```

Comment: Oh yeah wow, simply python. What was I thinking.. Thanks a bunch!